# How do you manage localized strings in Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, localization

I am starting to wrap up a large client project that has been in development for several years.

It makes fairly heavy use of the `NSLocalizedString()` macro to ask the system for localized versions of string constants that are hard-coded into the program.

If you run the `genstrings` command line tool on your source directory it will find all the constant strings that are referenced in calls to `NSLocalizedString()` and create a starting version of `Localizable.strings`. You then give that starting `Localizable.strings` file to your translators, who start take Localizable.strings in the starting language (English in this case) and create versions of Localizable.strings for each supported language.

The problem is that in some cases, I fetch strings from data structures. In that case I have the source string in a variable.

```
The genstrings utility does not know how to handle this case:

#define K_STRING_TO_LOCALIZE @“This is the string to localize"
...
NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedString(K_STRING_TO_LOCALIZE, nil);
```

or this case:

```
NSString *stringToLocalize = @“This is the string to localize";
...
NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedString(stringToLocalize, nil);
```

(Assume that in both above cases the string gets defined somewhere else.)

In those case you need to manually add the "edge case" strings to `Localizable.strings`.

However, if you then do new development and add more strings, and more calls to
`NSLocalizedString()`, you can't run genstrings on your program again without overwriting the strings you put into it by hand.

It appears that `Localizable.strings` doesn't honor #import statements, so you also can't have a block of programmatically generated strings to be localized and a separate block that you enter manually for the edge cases.

What are some options for managing this?

### EDIT:

Better example:

I have a function in my shared `Utils` object called  `showAlertControllerWithTitle:message:showCancelButton:okButtonAction:` that displays a custom variant of an alert controller.

Internally, the function calls NSLocalizedString on the title and message parameters that are passed to it. That way you don't have to write all that boilerplate code for each call.
Here is an example call:

```
[[Utils sharedUtils] 
  showAlertControllerWithTitle: @"Error loading collection file"
  message: message
  showCancelButton: FALSE
  okButtonAction: nil];
```

The message string is generated programmatically. The title string is a fixed string.

However, since the `showAlertControllerWithTitle` function calls NSLocalizedString with a variable, not a compile-time constant string, the genstrings tool does not "see" that string and added it to the `Localized.strings` file.

Comment: You need to update your question with real examples because it's difficult see what the problem is with the two contrived examples you posted.

Comment: Your `showAlertControllerWithTitle:message:showCancelButton:okButtonAction:` method should not be calling `NSLocalizedString`. That's not the proper place for those calls. You should be passing in strings that are already localized.